# Magento 2 date picker validation

Tags: magento2, javascript, mixins

Does anyone know how to restrict past day selection in magento 2 date picker using JS mixing.

This is the frontend HTML Block That We Copied from the browser.

```
<input class="input-text _has-datepicker" type="text" data-bind="
hasFocus: focused,
datepicker: { storage: value, options: options },
attr: {
    id: uid,
    value: value,
    name: inputName,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
    'aria-required': required,
    'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
    disabled: disabled
}" id="OA2254" value="" name="oa_date" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="on">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict date range with pass correct `options` to `Date` component and you don't need to create any additional mixins.

You need to pass `minDate` with value like `new Date()`

Example with XML:

```xml
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- ... -->
                        <item name="minDate" xsi:type="string">new Date()</item>
                    </item>
```

See all available options in https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/